# A word for something that comes to mind before other things?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is this epistemic phenomenon X and we might take different approaches in explaining it. But one or more approaches come to mind sooner that others, perhaps because they are more well known or more received or ... .

Is there any word for such feature? Words such as "at hand", "close", "available" seem to me to have other connotations.

Comment: *precocious* - appearing or developing early

Answer (score 2):

The first word that comes to mind (wink) is **obvious**.

> "...perhaps because they are more well known or more received or **more obvious**."

---

[**Definition:**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obvious)
*easy to see, recognize, or understand.*

---

Many synonyms of obvious would also work, for example:

- apparent
- accessible
- straightforward
- explicit

etc.

Answer (score 1):

My initial suggestion is [***initial.***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20initial)

> existing or occurring at the beginning.
>
> *"our initial impression was favourable"*

Comment: _Initial_ is precisely the word that means 'comes before others'. It's just the Latin word for 'first', and that's what 'first' means. And that's the epistemic sense, all right.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the word **familiar** ; easy to recognize because of being seen or heard before.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for "salient" and I came to this page with no luck. Now I found it and thought maybe someone else is looking for this. Salient means most noticeable or important, which for a given subject is the word you might be looking for.